# Outlook on Mac: Move email messages between different accounts

Tags: email, ms-office

I am using a Macbook with Outlook, with three mail accounts configured.

I want to be able to move an email from one account with drag & drop to another mail account in the left sidebar.

This works fine for Outlook on Windows, but in Outlook it just does not work at all. Even with right click on the email > copy (or move?) > I can just select other folders in the same account.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to try moving with drag & drop but exporting and importing works well.

Exporting : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-items-to-an-archive-file-in-outlook-for-mac-281a62bf-cc42-46b1-9ad5-6bda80ca3106

Importing : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-email-messages-contacts-and-other-items-into-outlook-for-mac-6cc48404-a65c-4b8c-a12a-95a905249414

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to have a gmail account and let Outlook set it up automatically? If you let it do that, it insists on sync'ing through iCloud and prevents from dragging emails between accounts ("for your convenience", as it dares to say)!

One workaround is to click on "Not Google?" when it presents you with the iClould sync warning dialog. Then it will offer you a choice of manual setups. Just choose imap/pop. All defaults were filled correctly for once (Aug. 2021), just enter your password. Now it's setup correctly and you can drag emails between accounts.

FYI, the previous workaround was to start setting up the new mail account with a bogus email address from a bogus domain name Outlook does not know about. Then do as previously, choose to setup the account as imap/pop, correct the email name, etc...